# How to use Python and R effectively on internet-separated machine?

Tags: python, r, anaconda

Due to company security policy, laptops provided to staff are internet-separated.  I was told that if, say, I want to run R or Python, I'd need to download the installation file from the web using my own internet-enabled computer, save it to a secured hard drive provided by the company to transfer the installation file, and put the file into company laptop.

But during regular use of R and Python, we need to download new packages/ package updates from time to time.  How best should I manage this situation?  (I suppose using Anaconda to manage R/ Python installations will face problems too.)

Comment: "I'd need to download the installation file from the web using my own internet-enabled computer" <- Does that mean your private computer?

Comment: Ask IT to install the libraries and IDE that you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Sembei Norimaki, having IT handle the installations would probably be desirable.

If you have to manage these things yourself, you can use the miniCRAN package:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/miniCRAN/index.html

You can set up miniCRAN and install packages from there, instead of using CRAN (i.e. the internet) directly. Of course, doing so entails that you have to update your offline repository routinely.